# re-indexing in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table which already contains an index in MySQL.  I added some rows to the table, do I need to re-index the table somehow or does MySQL do this for me automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be done automatically. This is the reason, why sometimes we don't want to create indexes -- rebuilding of parts of indexes on inserting have small but not empty overhead in performance.

Comment: To be exact, it doesn't rebuild the index.  It just adds to it (which may entail rebuilding part of it).

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen yeah, you are absolutely right! Rebuilding whole indexes will blow away any reasonable work with DB. I've added a correction

Answer (score 1):

If you define an index in MySQL then it will always reflect the current state of the database unless you have deliberately disabled indexing. As soon as indexing is re-enabled, the index will be brought up to date. Usually indexing is only disabled during large insertions for performance reasons.

There is a cost associated with each index on your table. While a good index can speed up retrieval times immensely, every index you define slows insertion by a small amount. The insertion costs grow slowly with the size of the database. This is why you should only define indexes you absolutely need if you are going to be working on large sets of data.

If you want to see what indexes are defined, you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to have a look at a particular table.

Answer (score 1):

No, you didn't need to rebuild index.
Record insertion will automatically affect old index..